# Laravel - Set Default Value for Relation Models

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table accounts:

```
act_id,
act_name,
act_address
```

And I have a table addresses:

```
add_id,
add_street1,
<other fields you'd expect in an address table>
```

accounts.act_address is a foreign key to addresses.add_id. In Laravel, I have my Account model:

```
use LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Account extends Ardent
{
    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $table = 'accounts';

    protected $primaryKey = 'act_id';

    public static $rules = array
    (
        'act_name' => 'required|unique:accounts'
    );

    protected $fillable = array
    (
        'act_name'
    );

    public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Address', 'add_id', 'act_address');
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have my one-to-one relationship setup here. (Of course, the Address model has a 'belongsTo' as well). This all works.

The thing is, the address foreign key is nullable, as accounts don't require addresses. So, if I try to access the Account->address when it doesn't have one, I'll get a 'trying to access property of non-object' error.

What I'd like to do is set Account->address to a new Address object (all fields empty), if the account record doesn't have one set.

What I've been able to do is either create a second method in the model:

```
public function getAddress()
{
    return empty($this->address) ? new Address() : $this->address;
}
```

Or, add it on the fly:

```
if (empty($account->address))
    $account->address = new Address();
```

The first solution is really close, but I'd really like to keep the functionality of accessing address as a property instead of a method.

**So, my question is:

How can I have Account->address return new Address() if Account->address is empty/null?**

Oh, and I tried overriding the $attributes like so:

```
protected $attributes = array
(
    'address' => new Address()
);
```

But that throws an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use accessor:

**Edit: Since it is `belongsTo` not `hasOne` relation, it is a bit tricky - you can't associate a model to non-existing one, for the latter has no id**:

```
public function getAddressAttribute()
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists('address', $this->relations)) $this->load('address');

    $address = ($this->getRelation('address')) ?: $this->getNewAddress();

    return $address;
}

protected function getNewAddress()
{
    $address = $this->address()->getRelated();

    $this->setRelation('address', $address);

    return $address;
}
```

However, now you need this:

```
$account->address->save();
$account->address()->associate($account->address);
```

which is not very convenient. You can alternatively save newly instantiated address in `getNewAddress` method, or override Account `save` method, to do the association automatically. Anyway for this relation I'm not sure if it makes sense to do it.. For `hasOne` it would play nice.

---

**Below is the way how it should look like for `hasOne` relation**:

```
public function getAddressAttribute()
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists('address', $this->relations)) $this->load('address');

    $address = ($this->getRelation('address')) ?: $this->getNewAddress();

    return $address;
}

protected function getNewAddress()
{
    $address = $this->address()->getRelated();

    $this->associateNewAddress($address);

    return $address;
}

protected function associateNewAddress($address)
{
    $foreignKey = $this->address()->getPlainForeignKey();

    $address->{$foreignKey} = $this->getKey();

    $this->setRelation('address', $address);
}
```

You could do all this in single accessor, but this is the way it 'should' look like.

Comment: That does what I need as far as returning a new Address object, but when I'm creating an object with $account->address()->save(new Address($params)), it doesn't work. It creates both the account and the address, but the accounts.act_id does get set to addresses.add_id.

Comment: Show the code and what the issue is. It has nothing to do with method call `$account->address()` so it can't interfere with its `save` method. Btw I changed `getNewAddress` to avoid explicitly calling `new Address`.

Comment: And, are you sure the relations are OK? `hasOne` means, that `Address` table holds foreign key related to `Account` table primary key. Your tables are hard to read, but it seems that you have it wrong.

Comment: While I did state this is a one-to-one relationship, it's actually setup as a many-to-one. Several accounts can point to the same address. So, the accounts table just has a foreign key to the address.add_id column. I do the same thing with two other tables and it works fine. But, that foreign key is required, so I don't run into the issue that I originally proposed. I'm updating my post with more info.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. So the relations are wrong, you need `Account belongsTo Address`, `Address hasMany Account`. I'll adjust the code for this setup  in a moment.

Comment: Ah. You know, I think you're right. Because I was thinking of this as a one-to-one, I had it in my head the other way around. It does make more sense to say Account hasOne Address and Address belongsTo Account. But, I guess my setup will have to force me to go the other way. So I guess I'm just left with how to rewrite what you posted.

Comment: The getAddressAttribute() is exactly what I need for getting an empty default model.